# LaTex Jupyter Notebook "Undefined Control Sequence"

Tags: pdf, python

I am attempting to save down a Jupyter notebook to a PDF using LaTex. I just installed the latest version of LaTex through Jupyter terminal but when I run

`jupyter nbconvert --to pdf mynotebook.ipynb`

Inside my directory, I receive an error saying

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\HyPsd@expand@utfvii ... {~{####1}}}\UTFviii@loop
                                                  \count@ "E0 \@tempcnta "F0...
l.394 \end{document}
```

My notebook is not the issue since I created a new empty notebook with a single commented cell and still get the error. I have no issues exporting to other files (e.g. --to LaTex)

Does anyone have any ideas? I've researched this issue on Git, SE, and SO, and there is no definitive fix.

Comment: it appears you have a very old latex where inputenc is not loaded by default and you need `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`